# unable to get the changes made in index of phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm unable to get the changes made in the index of PhoneGap Android.
Actually I have added everything into my eclipse android project with phonegap.
When i change that index.html page, I'm not getting the changes in emulator.
Those changes are not reflecting in the emulator. It is remaining with same page like Helloworld.

Answer (score 0):

After making the changes to index.html, you need to select its enclosing project and choose Run As -> Android Application from the right click menu.

Comment: ya.i did the same thing.but it is showing the previous result.in the sense same result which i got when i run the application for the first time.

Comment: and you saved the changed index.html? File->Save